# Create a bookmark for a YouTube Live video

Tags: youtube

I would like to create a bookmark for some of the live channels on YouTube so that I can access them using keywords on Chrome (Search Engines) or Firefox.

The problem is that if I create a bookmark/keyword to a channel like Skynews (at the moment the address is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XOacA3RYrXk ) the ID changes often and I will have to update my bookmark/keyboard on a regular basis. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to live stream: "Stream now" and "Events".

Events always create their own videoID, it is not possible to have a permanent bookmark for the most recent event.

Stream now can be reached by `<channelURL>/live`, so in your example: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoMdktPbSTixAyNGwb-UYkQ/live. Unfortunately for you, the channel has not used "stream now" since January.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So are you saying that what I am asking is impossible? I will have to change the link anytime it changes? why does YouTube change it? how often does it happen?